# Save descendence in family tree with a recursive function in Python

Tags: dictionary, recursion, family-tree

I have a dictionary of a family tree with the name of the child as the key and their dad's and mom's name in a list as the value.

```
d = { 
'Kevin': ('Tom', 'Marge'), 
'Marge': ('John', 'Mary'), 
'Elle': ('Tom', 'Marge'), 
'Seth': ('Tom', 'Marge'), 
'Mary': ('Carl', 'Elena'), 
'Tom': ('Joseph', 'Alice'), 
'Alice': ('Rob', 'Amy'), 
'John': ('James', 'Elena'), 
'Joseph': ('Adam', 'Emma'), 
'James': ('Nick', 'Maria') }
```

I need to write a recursive function so that it returns True when there is a descendence between two people. If there is a descendance, it has to print out the chain of relations, i.e:

```
>>> print("Is there a lineage?", lineage('Amy', 'Kevin', d))
Amy
Alice
Tom
Kevin
Is there a lineage? True
```

Otherwise if there isn't one:

```
>>> print("Is there a lineage?", lineage('Mary', 'Alice', d))
Is there a lineage? False
```

This is what I've got so far. It seems to return True or False consistantly, but I'm having troubles figuring out how to save the path between the two people.

```
line = []

def lineage(parent, child, d):
    dad, mom = d[child][0], d[child][1]
    
    try:
        if parent in d[child]:
            line.append(parent)
        else:
            try:
                lineage(parent, dad, d)
            except:
                lineage(parent, mom, d)
        
        return True
    
    except:
        return False
```

I'm new to recursion, so any ideas or help on how to approach this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I made your function return the path, instead of `True`, when a path exists.
- I recommend avoiding `try / except` here.

It is true that trying to access `d[child]` without checking that `child` is in `d` might result in an Exception. However, this is the base-case of your recursion; your code will be easier to understand if the base case is clearly identified with an explicit `if` at the beginning of your function, rather than with an obscure "some Exception happened" with no explanation at the end of your function.

```py
def lineage(parent, child, d):
    if parent == child:
        return [child]
    elif child not in d:
        return False
    else:
        dad, mom = d[child][0], d[child][1]
        path_via_dad = lineage(parent, dad, d)
        if path_via_dad:
            path_via_dad.append(child)
            return path_via_dad
        else:
            path_via_mom = lineage(parent, mom, d)
            if path_via_mom:
                path_via_mom.append(child)
                return path_via_mom
            else:
                return False
```

Here is a shorter, equivalent version, relying on the specific behaviour of logical operator `or` in python:

```py
def lineage(parent, child, d):
    if parent == child:
        return [child]
    elif child not in d:
        return False
    else:
        dad, mom = d[child][0], d[child][1]
        path = lineage(parent, dad, d) or lineage(parent, mom, d)
        if path:
            path.append(child)
        return path
```

Testing:

```py
>>> lineage('Amy', 'Kevin', d)
['Amy', 'Alice', 'Tom', 'Kevin']
>>> lineage('Mary', 'Alice', d)
False
```